# using a mocked database instead of a real database

Tags: c#, moq

Is there a way to mock the main database of a web project?
I created a sample project without any database (no physical db).
I did search how to make aan MVC project load mocked data using the master connection string.

Comment: Usually you don't mock the database, but the data store. This is why there is a layer between the physical database and the layers that use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.Net Core, You can use In Memory Database. [The following link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) explains the way of doing it.

You can simple use in-memory database like below:

```
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddInMemoryDatabase()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase());

    serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```